# How to hide the Copy/Paste menu after it shows on screen?

Tags: android, copy-paste

I don't want to disable or to block the functionality of Copy/Paste menu.

But once the user opened this menu and then he moved to unrelated task in my app, I wish to programmatically close it.

How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: is this for and EditText or a TextView?

Comment: @JoeFrostick for EditText

Comment: remove focus the edittext

Comment: yourEditText.clearFocus() will do the magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if(mEditText != null){
        mEditText.clearFocus();
    }
}
```